# Add listener to bootstrap modal getting closed using Javascript ONLY

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I want to fire an event every time the modal gets closed. Since it can be closed from multiple places I just want to add a listener to when it *does* get closed. I have browsed the internet for possible solutions for listening to the bootstrap modal close event but they all use JQuery. Is there any way I can do that using just plain javascript?

Here is the solution in JQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myBtn").click(function(){
    $("#myModal").modal("show");
  });
  $("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    alert('The modal is now hidden.');
  });
});
</script>
```

If I could add a listener to `hidden.bs.modal` using javascript alone that would be great. I've tried

```
document.addEventListener("hidden.bs.modal", function(){
  console.log('modal closed!')
});
```

but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

`hidden.bs.modal` is not an event, so there's no way to listen for it directly with `addEventListener`.

What you can do is listen for attribute changes of a specific element, using a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

You need to setup a call back that is essentially your event handler, and attach that to a mutation observer, and then set the observer to observer your modal element.

```js
const target = document.getElementById('target');
document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', e => target.classList.add('hidden', 'bs', 'modal'));

document.getElementById('btn2').addEventListener('click', e => target.classList.remove('hidden', 'bs', 'modal'));

const config = { attributes: true, childList: false, subtree: false };

function callback(mutationsList, observer)
{
  for(let mutation of mutationsList)
  {
    if(mutation.attributeName == 'class')
    {
      let cls = mutation.target.getAttribute('class');
      if(cls.includes('hidden') && cls.includes('bs') && cls.includes('modal'))
      {
        console.log('the modal is now hidden');
      }
    }
  }
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

observer.observe(target, config);
```

```css
.hidden
{
 color:green;
}
.bs
{
 background: red;
}
.modal
{
 border:black dashed 3px;
}
```

```html
<p id="target">hello</p>
<p><input type="button" id="btn1" value="switch on"></p>
<p><input type="button" id="btn2" value="switch off"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I see that this method only adds listeners to any buttons that can close the modal. Can we also detect if the user clicks outside the modal (that causes the modal to get closed)?

Comment: The buttons are an example of a way to close the modal. The meat of the code actually listens for a change in the class of the modal element, as your jQuery code does.